# django, X-CSRFToken is set incorrectly in request header

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, csrf

basically, i got this to actually send a csrf token to the frontend and set it there in cookie section in application tab in dev window in the browser:

```py
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return JsonResponse({'csrftoken':get_token(request)})
```

in react side:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/csrf/').then((res)=>{
      console.log(res.data)
      Cookies.set('csrftoken',res.data.csrftoken)
    })
  },[])

  let handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/", signup, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get("csrftoken") },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setDisabled(true)
        setIsUp(true)

        setTimeout(()=>{setIsUp(false)
        redirect('/')},3000)
        

      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.response.data)
        let err = e.response.data
        setError(err);
      });
  };
```

on my local machine (on the local hosts):

i get these values to match:
[image]

[image]

as you can see both `Cookie` and `X-CSRFToken` are matching in request header, however, in production:

[image]

[image]

and the weirder part is that in request header the name of the key in local host is `Cookie`, but in production it is `cookie` (c and C difference)

and of course I get an error when i make a post request in production server:

```
<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
</div>
<div id="info">
<h2>Help</h2>
<p>Reason given for failure:</p>
<pre> CSRF token from the &#x27;X-Csrftoken&#x27; HTTP header incorrect.
</pre>
<p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
<a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/">Django’s
```

help me understand the problem, and KINDLY help me understand the correct way to actually retrieve csrf token in case it was missing from `application` tab in dev console in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I think you are puzzling things, CSRF is always there by default, which means you do not require to generate a `csrf-token`.
For `Axios` just use it like this:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
    
axios.post("/url",{
          key: value
      })
     .then(function (response) {
          //your code....
      })
     .catch(function (error) {
          //error handling
     });
```